# Unity Prefab Issue, different reactions from different prefabs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, prefab

So I've hit a wall in a unity project, and I've been unable to even find a similar problem. I'm not sure how to easily describe it, but here goes:

I have a prefab (a simple 3D object triggered on mouse click/finger tap). It is meant to act as a button (it cannot be a UI button for various reasons). I have a bunch of them. Each button has a script attached, so that when the button is pressed, it will display some text and and some images. However, this is not working.

To test it, I put down a few of these buttons. I filled in the script box for two of them, lets call them A and B. They were directed to the same UI elements, but each was given a different set of images to produce. However, when I test it, it only calls the images from B. If A is the only one set up, all the buttons call from A, even without a script attached.

I need some way to refresh the assigned starting "values" for the variables. So that it will pull from what I assigned them in the editor only when clicked on, and not before. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question and use Unity-specific terms when when referring to different objects in the Unity environment. Also provide more details as to what components your prefabs contain as well as the code you've got in your scripts and how these prefabs are enabled in this scene.

Comment: click Edit, and show your script

Comment: you are attaching the script to the buttons? or do you attach the scripts to a general objects and then a a OnClick function to the buttons?

Comment: Not even that, I'm doing 'input.getmousebuttondown' because it has to also function when tapped via a touch screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link  [Instantiating Prefabs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html) from the unity site.

A possible solution would be to set a global Boolean variable for each button (prefab). If button 1 is active, set the variable to true and in for buttons 2 and 3 make them turn to false for inactive.

I suggest designing your script this way for each button. After the button is pressed refreshed the values in the variable for each button and check these values again once a button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be almost there.

```
public class A : Mono {
    public ImageToShow Image; // Assign this in inspector

    void OnMouseDown() {
         Image.DoYourThing(); // Do whatever you need to here for the image
    }
}
```

When this is on many different "Prefabs" if you handle the prefabs correctly, each button will have its own instance with its own reference to the image you assigned inside the inspector.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html

Link for OnMouseDown.

Each button can have the SAME script, you just neeed to make sure that each prefab instance you have SAVED has the correct image assigned to its script.

Hope this helps.

Edit: Doing it this way, each button will be "active" but wont do anything if not tapped. If you tap or click an inactive game object (which is your button because its not a GUI element) no method on that object will be called.

Comment: That does not work for it, or I may have the prefabs handled wrong. I think the issue is that since they all have the same script, the last one that is loaded, is the one that is considered "real" and its images are the official ones for all.